# Regex to match '-' delimited alphanumeric words

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to test if user type only alphanumeric value or one "-".

```
hello-world                 -> Match
hello-first-world           -> match
this-is-my-super-world      -> match
hello--world                -> NO MATCH
hello-world-------this-is   -> NO MATCH
-hello-world                -> NO MATCH (leading dash)
hello-world-                -> NO MATCH (trailing dash)
```

Here is what I have so far, but I dont know how to implement the "-" sign to test it if it is only once without repeating.

```
var regExp = /^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/;
```

Comment: Can it begin or end with a "-" ?

Comment: no, it should not start or end with "-"

Comment: Should "foo" be a match, or not a match?

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

This will only match sequences of one or more sequences of alphanumeric characters separated by a single `-`. If you do not want to allow single words (e.g. just `hello`), replace the `*` multiplier with `+` to allow only one or more repetitions of the last group.

Comment: Perfect, clearly but briefly explained, and not over-complex. Live example: http://jsbin.com/iceho3/2

Comment: Just for my knowledge: what does the `?:` mean?

Comment: @Nivas: It's not a capture group. (Normally parens are capture groups.) http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/ By putting the optional additional bit in a group, Gumbo can then use `*` to indicate zero or more of the sequences in that group.

Comment: sorry guys, i have probably didnt say it clearly, but the single "-" should not be there. It could be there, it should not at all.

Comment: @Nivas: `(?:…)` is a so called non-capturing group. It’s similar to the normal group `(…)` but you can’t reference the sequence that is matched by its content.

Comment: **(?:regex)** Non-capturing parentheses group the regex so you can apply regex operators, but do not capture anything and do not create backreferences. ref: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: @praethorian: In that case replace the `*` multiplier by `?`. That means the group is optional.

Comment: @praethorian: What do you mean? Gumbo's expression doesn't allow just a `-`. (It also disallows leading and trailing `-`s.): http://jsbin.com/iceho3/3

Comment: @paethorian and @Gumbo, the `*` also makes it optional. what he probably wants is to replace the `*` with `+`

Answer (score 5):

Here you go (this works).

```
var regExp = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+([-]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$/;
```

letters and numbers greedy, single dash, repeat this combination, end with letters and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`(^-)|-{2,}|[^a-zA-Z-]|(-$)` looks for invalid characters, so zero matches to that pattern would satisfy your requirement.

Comment: this fails on cases w/ a leading dash `-one-two-three`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this works because I haven't done regex in awhile, but it sounds like you need the following:

/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$/

You're requirement is split up in the following:

- One or more alphanumeric characters to start (that way you ALWAYS have an alphanumeric starting.
- The second half entails a "-" followed by one or more alphanumeric characters (but this is optional, so the entire thing is required 0 or more times). That way you'll have 0 or more instances of the dash followed by 1+ alphanumeric.

I'm just not sure if I did the regex properly to follow that format.

Comment: Close, but `\w` allows `_`. (Some other edits: Use a non-capturing group rather than capturing, no need for `[]` around `\w`, and need the `$` at the end; result: `/^\w+(?:-\w+)*$/`). But again, the OP didn't want `_`.

Comment: putting `\w` inside brackets is not neccessary, otherwise it looks fine, although if you start it with `^` you probably meant to end it with `$`. Also he probably wants the last `*` to be a `+` although his examples are not clear on the subject.

Comment: `[A-z]` matches all uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters, plus `[`, `]`, `_`, `^`, backslash, and backtick.  To match just the letters, you have to use use `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: I'm good at knowing HOW a regex should act, but the little things about it always get me... I guess that's why I explained how to break it up in groups.

Answer (score 0):

The expression can be simplified to: `/^[^\W_]+(?:-[^\W_]+)+$/`

Explanation:

```
^             match the start of string
[^\W_]+       match one or more word(a-zA-Z0-9) chars 
(?:-[^\W_]+)+ match one or more group of '-' follwed by word chars
$             match the end of string
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/MODQxw/1