# How to match trailing linefeed with regexp?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate string so that trailing whitespace/linefeed (PHP_EOL, \n, \r, \t and " ") is not allowed. Here's the code:

```
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?[^\s]$/';
$value = 'foo' . PHP_EOL;
$status = preg_match($pattern, $value);
```

With trailing PHP_EOL and "\n" expression matches, with "\t", "\r" and " " it doesn't.

What is the proper expression to disallow all whitespace/linefeed at the end of the string, including PHP_EOL and "\n"?

Comment: idea was to **validate** input, not filter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `$` is, that it matches at the end of the string  [*or immediately before a newline character that is the last character in the string (by default)*](http://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.anchors.php), therefore you can not match a `\n` at the end of the string using the `$` anchor.

To avoid that you can use `\z` (see [escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.escape.php) on php.net), that will always match at the end of the string (also independently of the `multiline` modifier).

So a solution would be

```
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?(?<!\s)\z/';
```

`(?<!\s)` is a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that is true if there is no whitespace character before `\z`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$pattern = '/\s(?=\s*$)/';
$value = 'foo'. PHP_EOL;
$status = preg_match($pattern, $value);

if(!$status) {
    echo "Allow";
}
else {
    echo "Not Allow";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a basic "no trailing delimiters" problem, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3787875/20938), but with spaces instead of hyphens.

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/'
```

This regex assumes the delimiter can be any kind of whitespace, and there can be more than one of them.  If you only want to allow one space character (`\x20`), this will do it:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/'
```