# JS regex string validation for slug

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have an app, that allowing the end user to enter his desired slug. What I am looking for is a regex that check if the slug is valid.

In general, as valid a mean a string that start and ends with a latin leter, divided by dashes but not more than one dashes.

More specific, the following is correct:

```
one-two-three
```

The following are not:

```
one---two-thee-
-one-two-three
one-two-three-
```

So with the following regex I am somewhow ok, but how can I check if in the middle of the string there are no more than two dashes ?

```
^[a-z][a-z][a-z]$
```

Is there a better way to write this regex, in order to meet my validation creteria ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

http://regexpal.com/ can be a great webpage for checking your regexes as you write them. A handy tool :).

Having a look at yours, should it accept capital letters/numbers? If so maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787875/regex-to-match-delimited-alphanumeric-words) will help :

> /^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
>
> This will only match sequences of one or more sequences of
>   alphanumeric characters separated by a single -. If you do not want to
>   allow single words (e.g. just hello), replace the * multiplier with +
>   to allow only one or more repetitions of the last group.

Here's a link to a [live sample](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=104056) from the same thread to demonstrate.

Changing around the A-Za-z0-9 inside the squares will allow you to only accept capitals,non-capitals or numbers as is appropriate to you.

Good luck and let me know if you have any more questions ! :)

Answer (score 17):

My personal favourite :

```
^[a-z](-?[a-z])*$
```

*Begin with a lowercase letter; then more lower or maybe a hyphen, but not without another lower right after it.*

Comment: This worked for me, no other "approved" answers worked for a single optional dash in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 4):

```
^[a-z][a-z\-]*[a-z]$
```

actually this should be your regex
and your validation should be tested in two phases.

The first one by this regex, which will be a basic test, the second one can be done by splitting on hiphens and checking again the same regex on the splitted strings.

Comment: This not seem to work. I have test it and matching this slug too : one----two-thee that's not valid based on my creteria

Comment: This worked for me, no other "approved" answers worked for a single optional dash in the middle of a word.